# javascript device orientation events not handled in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, device-orientation

I have a recent problem using the deviceorientation event in Chrome on more than one mobile device (android and ios). It works in Safari and FireFox. I'm using a node.js server, and am using a mobile client to control immersive sound positioning.

My code worked in Chrome until 2 days ago. It still works in Safari and FireFox.

The code is simple, and according to examples:

```
    //capture device orientation
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.handleOrientation);
```

On testing with:

if (!window.DeviceOrientationEvent)
  alert("Device orientation not possible");

I get the alert message.

I see that in the example, found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation#Orientation_values_explained

This example does work in Chrome. Could it be that secure communication with the server is now required to access the gyroscope capabilities?

Comment: Can you also show handleOrientation?

Comment: @zero298 - It's a member function of a mobile device object. I tried making it global, to no avail. The frustrating thing is that it is a recent malfunction, and it only doesn't work with Chrome.    handleOrientation: function(event) {.....